# how to make rectangle for imageView frame as a subview in objective c

Tags: ios

how to make rectangle for imageView frame as a subview in objective c?
inside view controller i've a view , inside that view i want to put an imageView , and imageView frame should be less than the frame of the view frame and imageView should be in the centre of the view frame.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, set the imageView's size, secondary, set the imageView's coordinates, here is code:

```
    UIView *container = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 200, 200)];
    container.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    [self.view addSubview:container];

    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
    imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [container addSubview:imageView];

    CGRect f = imageView.frame;
    f.origin.x = CGRectGetWidth(container.bounds) / 2.0f - CGRectGetWidth(f) / 2.0;
    f.origin.y = CGRectGetHeight(container.bounds) / 2.0f - CGRectGetHeight(f) / 2.0f;
    imageView.frame = f;
```

or set the imageView's center(Alert! The imageView add to the `self.view`!)

```
    UIView *container = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 200, 200)];
    container.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    [self.view addSubview:container];

    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
    imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [self.view addSubview:imageView];

    imageView.center = container.center;
```

Also, you can use autolayout, like this:

```
    UIView *container = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 200, 200)];
    container.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    [self.view addSubview:container];

    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [container addSubview:imageView];
    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

    NSLayoutConstraint *c1 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:imageView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1 constant:100];
    NSLayoutConstraint *c2 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:imageView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1 constant:100];
    NSLayoutConstraint *c3 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:imageView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:container attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1 constant:0];
    NSLayoutConstraint *c4 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:imageView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:container attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY multiplier:1 constant:0];
    c1.active = YES;
    c2.active = YES;
    c3.active = YES;
    c4.active = YES;
```

All of the solutions above will put the imageView at the center of `container`

[image: result1]